# On the solutions of system of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $n$ variables

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Consider the following two system of n homogeneous polynomials in n variables of degree $d$ with complex coefficients:

**System 1 ($S_1$):**

$f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$\vdots$

$f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$ and

**System 2 ($S_2$):**

$x_1 f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$x_2 f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$\vdots$

$x_n f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$.

**System 3 ($S_3$):**

$x_1^2 f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$x_2^2 f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$\vdots$

$x_n^2 f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$.

I am interested in understanding the relation between the zeros of systems 1,2 and 3.  I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to calculate the complete solution of the systems $S_2$ and $S_3$? Also, how they are related to the solutions of the system $S_1$?

Thanks for your time and consideration. Have a good day.

Comment: S2 and S3 have the same solution set. A point is a solution of S2 if and only if it is a solution of S3. (There might be higher multiplicity when considering S3; more precisely the solutions of S2 and S3 may have different scheme structure. But ignoring multiplicities, the sets of solutions are the same.)

Comment: @ZachTeitler But I want to understand these multiplicities. Any idea how they change when we go from S1 to S2 and S2 to S3? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions to system $S_2$ is formed by the union of the solutions to $2^n$ systems indexed by $I\subseteq [n]$, in which $f_i=0$ for $i\in I$ and $x_j=0$ for all $j\in [n]\setminus I$. This includes $I=[n]$ corresponding to system $S_1$.

As a starting point for information about systems of polynomial equations, you can check [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations).